# Is having hashes of document certificates in IOTA blockchain for tamper proof a good use case for IOTA?

Tags: iota-network

I have a application where I want to store a SHA256 hash of a document in a Blockchain or a DLT. I want it to have a good life to it, like storing the SHA256 hash as a data in a transaction should not be deleted quickly. It should atleast last for 5-6 years.

Is IOTA a good fit for tamper-proof docs. I know IOTA already provides their own solutions but I am creating everything from UI to generating hashes. I only need to store hash somewhere safe, unique.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think using the IOTA tangle for long-term storage is a good idea. (Note that IOTA does not use a blockchain). While there are permanodes who store data for a longer time (but may not provide access for free), old transactions that are no longer needed will be regularly pruned from normal nodes (and the balances/UTXOs moved into automatic snapshots). And as the protocol is currrently still evolving, you would need multiple different ways of retrieving hashes of different age from the Tangle.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer.Do you have some suggestion for a blockchain that fits the use case except for ethereum?

Comment: Also, what if I run my own node? Is there a way to see out that my hashes are not deleted if I pay some value to keep my hashes for a long time?

Comment: probably every blockchain would fit better. I.e Bitcoin, Ethereum, Bitcoin cash, Stellar, ...)
When you run your own node, you can keep the transaction as long as you want. But as there is no real PoW involved, and others may have already deleted all your transactions, it proves nothing more than just keeping the hashes in a file on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a blueprint in the documentation to set up something similar with IPFS here:

https://docs.iota.org/docs/blueprints/0.1/tangle-data-storage/overview